# Is "as if" correct?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, idiomatic-language

A: I'm throwing a party tomorrow. You should come.

B didn't look very interested, but gave a nod as if he would consider it.

- Is "as if" correct here?
- Does the sentence make sense?

Comment: Would you please add what you think yourself about the sentences?

Comment: It's fine. Your question sounded as if you knew the answer too.

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you already know about "as if", what you've been able to find in your own Internet research, and what part of "as if" you're still unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is "correct".  It is standard English.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20if